# Download video with src url

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, video

I am trying to download video with src url "https://player.vimeo.com/video/210140332"  Is there a process that can be followed to download all this type of videos?

Answer (score 3):

Downloading videos from online video hosting services vary depending on the standards that they set.
For example, Vimeo states the following on their [Downloading videos](https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/229678128-Downloading-videos) page:

> **For Windows users:** Right-click on the link and choose “Save as” or “Save target as.”
>
> **For Mac users:** Hold down the Control key on your keyboard and click the link, then choose “Save link as” or “Download linked file"

However under the heading **Disabling the ability to download your videos** it states:

> Some people would rather not allow their videos to be downloaded, and we respect that. Under [Privacy Settings](https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/224819527-Changing-the-privacy-settings-of-your-videos), we let our members specify whether they want to allow downloading. If a member has disabled downloading, you won’t see the "Download" button on the video page.